# How to keep alignment when there is text in the middle?

Tags: align, amsmath

If I have text between two align blocks, I lose the alignment. Is there an easy way to solve this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
a^2 &= b^3+c^3+d^3 \\
a^2+d^3+z^4 &= b^3+c^3+d^3
\end{align}

Some other text

\begin{align}
a^2 &= b^3+c^3+d^3+b^3+c^3+d^3
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

The equals are not aligned:

[image]

Comment: well. I would like more flexibility.. not something short

Comment: ...so, what do you plan to place instead of `Some other text`. If what you're planning is a whole bunch of paragraphs, then sure, there are other options, but please specify this as part of your request. Realistic examples would help.